# Ruby on Rails Devise id='sign up'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So a few people have had this problem, but none of their code actually matches mine so their solutions aren't working.

Basically, whenever I try to access /users/:id it passes in the params correctly {'id' => '1'}, but then the page errors out on 'no user with id='sign_out'

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do



  devise_for :users, path: 'devise'



  get 'sessions/new'



  get 'intro', to: 'index#intro'

  root 'index#intro'

  authenticated :user do

    root 'index#homepage', as: :authenticated_root

  end

  devise_scope :user do

    get '/start', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: "login"

    get '/devise/sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: "logout"

    get '/signup', to: 'users#new', as: "signup"

  end



  get '/forgotPassword', to: 'index#forgotPassword'



  get '/homepage', to: 'index#homepage'

  get '/meetUs', to: 'index#meetUs'

  get '/makeSuggestion', to: 'index#makeSuggestion'

  get 'profile', to: 'index#profile'



  resources :suggestions

  resources :rewards

  resources :users

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

end
```

Code in controller erroring out:

```
  # GET /users/1

  # GET /users/1.json

  def show

      @users = User.find(params[:id])

  end
```

I'm pretty sure the issue has something to do with the routes thinking /users is both a resource of mine and of devise. But I don't know how to tell it to use the default route rails made as opposed to the one devise made.

If anyone could help, and try and explain why it's happening, that'd be great. Thanks in advance!

edit: Picks of the error and trace
[image: error]
[image: stack1]
[image: stack2]

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace of the error? Or, even better, are you able to re-create the problem on a brand new rails app in order to show a minimal reproduction example?

Comment: I edited to include the error message and trace

Comment: Can you show the link to sign out as well as the params from the server logs? I'm guessing it does not include '/devise/sign_out' in the the way your routes are set up. `users/sign_out` is pattern-matching to `users/:id`. Also, what is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: <%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, :class => "nav" %> but the thing is i'm logged in when this errors out

Comment: what is the output of `bundle exec rake routes | grep sign_out`?

Comment: @abax If your devise's sign out route has the default `method: :delete`, then your link also needs to specify `method: :delete`. By performing a `GET` action, rather than the necessary `DELETE` action, you're hitting the wrong controller.

Comment: ...And the error isn't "when you're signed in", it's **when you click the Log Out button**. That information is immensely crucial to your problem.

Comment: No, the error isn't when I click `log out`. Regardless of if I'm signed in or not, the user page always thinks id = "sign_out" and it's only the show for users. Not for any of my other controllers

Comment: @abax logout GET    /devise/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
    destroy_user_session DELETE /devise/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy

Comment: I agree with both of Tom's points. Searching for 'devise logout' yields `<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete) %>`.

Comment: The thing is, I've not pressed log out. I'm currently logged in and it is still saying this.